# Python Substring - Splitting nth number of Characters to the left of a certain string

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, substring

I have the following example string:

```
0015CB,0,0,01,006D,0016CF1,4,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00F4E7D,1,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,0008184,8,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FA704,9,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,0014EC8,2,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FAEEA,9,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FADE9,5,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FA5A5,3,000D
```

Please can you advise how I can get the 9 characters to left of every iteration of `"000D"`, so the first result would be:

```
0016CF1,4
```

second extraction would be:

```
00F4E7D,1
```

third would be:

```
0008184,8
```

etc. I've tried the split function and am struggling to grasp regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for a regex, you can use a combination of split and slice:

```
s = "0015CB,0,0,01,006D,0016CF1,4,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00F4E7D,1,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,0008184,8,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FA704,9,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,0014EC8,2,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FAEEA,9,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FADE9,5,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FA5A5,3,000D"

my_list = [e[-9:] for e in s.split(",000D")]
print(my_list)
```

output:

```
['0016CF1,4', '00F4E7D,1', '0008184,8', '00FA704,9', '0014EC8,2', '00FAEEA,9', '00FADE9,5', '00FA5A5,3', '']
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent hours trying to find a solution to this, much much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Something very close to this should work for you...

```
string = "0015CB,0,0,01,006D,0016CF1,4,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00F4E7D,1,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,0008184,8,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FA704,9,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,0014EC8,2,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FAEEA,9,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FADE9,5,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FA5A5,3,000D"
sub = []
search = "000D"
while string.find(search) != -1:
   pos = string.find(search)
   sub.append(string[pos-10:pos])
   string = string[pos+len(search):]
print(sub)
```

output:

```
['0016CF1,4,', '00F4E7D,1,', '0008184,8,', '00FA704,9,', '0014EC8,2,', '00FAEEA,9,', '00FADE9,5,', '00FA5A5,3,']
```

Just searching and substringing and then cutting the string down.

EDIT: I fixed the bug that was pointed out in the comments

Comment: This is an endless loop. Even if it worked it would be horribly inefficient. See [Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/).